# Browser is caching JavaScript file where it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

We've implemented a way to go around js caching issue when deploying new app version but it seems that it doesn't work as expected. Our approach is to change timestamp like here:

https://sgrouples.com/js/RequireMake-build.js?v=1349709973

So problem is that this file is cached regardless of 'v' value. The only suspicion I have now is that the script tag lives in the body not the header of the document. Can that be a cause ?

Here are response headers for that file:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=2678400
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Sat, 19 Jan 2013 10:42:32 GMT
ETag:W/"2679866-1358511264000"-gzip
Expires:Tue, 19 Feb 2013 10:42:32 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 18 Jan 2013 12:14:24 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
transfer-encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: How is your document cached? Maybe the updated `v=` in the document never reaches the client? Caching and cache-invalidating work as expected when opening the .js directly, in Firefox 18. What browser is your problem in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry for the trouble but there was a bug in our configuration so the v wasn't increased on our production servers. It works as expected.

Comment: you can mark this answer as the accepted answer by clicking on the green tick (when it lets you).